# How to invert colors using CSS on hover

Tags: css

I'm trying to make interactive cart buttons using CSS stylings. I want my "add to cart" button to invert colors (black n white only) on hover to enhance user experience.

CSS style:

```
.ryanAddButton {
  display:       inline-block;
  padding:       8px 0px;
  width:          390px;
  background:    -moz-linear-gradient(#000, #000);
  background:    -o-linear-gradient(#000, #000);
  background:    -webkit-linear-gradient(#000, #000);
  background:    linear-gradient(#000, #000);
  color:         #fff;
  font:          normal 700 20px/1 "Calibri", sans-serif;
  text-align:    center;
  text-shadow:   1px 1px 0 #000;
}
ryanAddButton:hover {
  background-color:white;
  color:black;
}
```

HTML snippet of the button:

```
<p  class ="ryanAddButton">Add to Cart</p>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your original `background` shorthand uses a gradient which is interpreted as a `background-image` and so your hover declaration does not override that property.

```css
.ryanAddButton {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 0px;
  width: 390px;
  /*
background:    -moz-linear-gradient(#000, #000);
background:    -o-linear-gradient(#000, #000);
background:    -webkit-linear-gradient(#000, #000);
background:    linear-gradient(#000, #000);
    */
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
  font: normal 700 20px/1"Calibri", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000;
}
.ryanAddButton:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<p class="ryanAddButton">Add to Cart</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there's a slight typo in your CSS.

**Solution 1 : (A simple one - a layman's solution) :**

Secondly, Paulie_D's answer is correct. However, just as another viewpoint, if you apply the background property, why not change the same property on `hover` :

```css
.ryanAddButton {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 0px;
    width: 390px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#000, #000);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#000, #000);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#000, #000);
    background: linear-gradient(#000, #000);
    color: #fff;
    font: normal 700 20px/1"Calibri", sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000;
}
.ryanAddButton:hover {
    background:white;
    color:black;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<p class="ryanAddButton">Add to Cart</p>
```

**Solution 2 : (A better solution - a designer/programmer's solution) :**

Your background property makes use of linear gradient. However, since both the colors are same, the use of linear gradient becomes redundant. Instead, you can get the color by making use of the background-color property. This is beneficial since you wouldn't need to use vendor prefix and at the same time the browser support would be much better on older browsers.

At the same time, it reduces several lines of code by just one :

```
background-color : black;
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

Change the background gradient in the ".ryanAddButton" for black, and you miss the dot for class in "ryanAddButton:hover", should be ".ryanAddButton:hover"

Answer (score 0):

Your background uses a gradient, which overlays the background colour. So even if you change the background colour *behind* the gradient, you won't see the change. You can override it by setting the entire `background` property, which will remove the gradient while also setting the background colour.

```
.ryanAddButton:hover{
  background:white; /* overrides all background properties */
  color:black;
}
```

You're also missing a `.` in your hover selector.

```css
.ryanAddButton{

display:       inline-block;
padding:       8px 0px;
width:          390px;
background:    -moz-linear-gradient(#000, #000);
background:    -o-linear-gradient(#000, #000);
background:    -webkit-linear-gradient(#000, #000);
background:    linear-gradient(#000, #000);
color:         #fff;
font:          normal 700 20px/1 "Calibri", sans-serif;
text-align:    center;
text-shadow:   1px 1px 0 #000;
}
.ryanAddButton:hover{
background:white;
color:black;
}
```

```html
<p  class ="ryanAddButton"> Add to Cart</p>
```